# PCL Incrementally registering clouds

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

in the provided PCL [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20191104212127/http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pairwise_incremental_registration.php#pairwise-incremental-registration) for how to incrementally register pairs of clouds with ICP, they describe and show the process.

They register a pair of clouds getting the transformation and an output cloud (but they don't do anything with the output cloud because it is the source cloud transformed to the target cloud). Then they take the source->target transformation and invert it to get the target->source transformation and accumulate it in a global transformation. Next, they apply the target->source transformation on the target cloud to get it into the source form and add the source to it. finally they apply the global transform to transform the transformed target + source.

So my question is, instead of gathering source->target transforms and inverting them, why not do target->source transforms to save inversion and not using output clouds from initial .align() steps?